Where does Thomas Aquinas give this definition of beauty?
Everyone quotes Thomas Aquinas as defining beauty as "id quod visum placet." No one gives a citation. Can any of you folks supply such citation?

The 'quote' is bastardized. What appears in are Summa Theologiae are pulchra enim dicuntur quae visa placent, "beautiful things are those which please when seen" (I.5.4 ad1); and pulchrum autem dicatur id cuius ipsa apprehensio placet, "what is said to be beautiful is that which, when perceived, pleases" (IIa.27.1 ad3).

For a comprehensive account, see Sevier, Aquinas on Beauty.

I believe you are looking for Summa Theologica, First Part, Question 5, Article 4, Reply to Objection 1. In the Benziger translation (1920) the passage reads:

Beauty and goodness in a thing are identical fundamentally; for they
are based upon the same thing, namely, the form; and consequently
goodness is praised as beauty. But they differ logically, for goodness
properly relates to the appetite (goodness being what all things
desire); and therefore it has the aspect of an end (the appetite being
a kind of movement towards a thing). On the other hand, beauty relates
to the cognitive faculty; for beautiful things are those which please
when seen. Hence beauty consists in due proportion; for the senses
delight in things duly proportioned, as in what is after their own
kind—because even sense is a sort of reason, just as is every
cognitive faculty. Now since knowledge is by assimilation, and
similarity relates to form, beauty properly belongs to the nature of a
formal cause.

